# Windows Search in Outlook 2013 on Remote Desktop Service Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, search, outlook-2013

I have a single server that runs Windows 2012 R2 (installed on a HP Proliant ML350 g8 with 16Gb or ram).
The server owns : Active Directory and RDS desktops.
I know that's not the best pratice but for 7 clients I won't use two servers... Anyway :
When users try to search for emails in Outlook (POP accounts, no Exchange), it doesn't work at all.
I already tried to rebuild the index, Outlook says that all objects are indexed.
I tried to put a user to administrators group.
I tried to put that same user outside of my RDS Organization Unit (which is more secured).
The result remains the same, it won't find anything.
In safe mode, it works but it's definetly not a solution.

I've been looking for this problem over serverfault and internet but didn't find a solution. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Windows Search services for search to work in Outlook on RDS. A caveat is about the index file that will grow as many users will use the RDS. Now the file on our server is 12 GB large and I'm looking for best practices to find the right compromise between peformances and file size.

One clue here: http://www.peters.com/Blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=112

BR